# Is the assigment of a vector function atomic? (Can't understand error)

Tags: memory-management, segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

I've got a segmentation fault from a program and I understand something is wrong, because I'm using an argument which is not allocated, but I don't really understand the inner workings of the error:

```
program MWE
      implicit none

      integer, allocatable :: b(:)

      call S(b)

      contains

      subroutine S(a)
              integer, intent(out) :: a(:)
              a = F(10) !I was expecting the error here
              ! but in the assigment not inside
              ! the function call.
      end subroutine

      function F(n) result(v)
              integer, intent(in) :: n
              integer :: v(n)
              print*, "Now comes the error"
              v = 1 !here, in this assignment
              print*, "We nevet get here"
      end function
end program
```

I understand that I'm declaring variable **a** as *allocatable*, and I know I'm passing it to subroutine S without allocating it.

However I would expect the function **F** to work just fine, as it is given **N** and thus it knows the size of **v**. I would expect the segmentation fault to appear after completing **F**, but before the assignment of its output to **a**.

Given that I get the error inside the function **F** I'm missunderstanding some inner working, but I don't know what.

This is the execution output:

```
Now comes the error

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f1bff9f28b0 in ???
#1  0x7f1bff9f1ae3 in ???
#2  0x7f1bff66c83f in ???
    at /build/glibc-vjB4T1/glibc-2.28/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c:0
#3  0x562fc494c262 in ???
#4  0x562fc494c3d3 in ???
#5  0x562fc494c30b in ???
#6  0x562fc494c40c in ???
#7  0x7f1bff65909a in __libc_start_main
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#8  0x562fc494c0b9 in ???
#9  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: IanH's answer gives many implementation details, but the essence is the moment you do something naughty all bets are off from then on. Here the first naughty thing you do is use an unallocated array as an actual argument corresponding to a dummy argument that does not have the allocatable attribute. From that point on an error may (or may not) get flagged.

Comment: I anderstand I'm doing something wrong and I expected it to fail, but it didn't fail where I was expecting it.

Comment: Quite. That is my point. Once one thing goes wrong anything is allowed to happen. Most implementations are pretty helpful nowadays and get near the right point, but you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that function call, gfortran passes a hidden argument to the function that tells the function where in memory it should put the result of the function.  That hidden argument species the storage associated with the `a` dummy argument in the subroutine.  That storage is invalid because the actual argument associated with the `a` dummy has not been allocated, therefore the storage that the function tries to put its result in is invalid, therefore you see an access violation inside the function.

The action associated with the assignment statement is implicit in getting the function to write directly into the storage of the thing on the left hand side of the assignment.

Different compilers (or the same compiler, for a function call or assignment statement with different characteristics) will implement this in different ways - for example, the function might write into a temporary that the calling code sets up and then copies over, or a buffer might be allocated inside the function that the calling code then needs to release.

You can examine how the gfortran compiler implements your program by inspecting the assembly (add -S to the command line), or one the intermediate representations (e.g. -fdump-tree-original)

Comment: thank you, I thought that the "temporary" was the standard so that's why I was confused